# Mutations undefined Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have an issue with mutations in Vuex - In my component I have passed the getters and mutations, so that I can used the data. However, the getters are getting passed down just fine and can be retrieved from the component, but regarding the mutations, they all seem to be getting undefined. I have another component with identical setup, which seems to work fine.

Here is the code related to the component I have an issue with: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/nlpvz0y6m

So far, I have tried retrieving the data by importing the whole `store`
but it isn't what I must do and not optimal.

Please advise further.

**store**:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    stats: {
      controls: {
        spin: false
      }
    },
    getters: {
      isSpinning: state => {
        return state.controls.spin;
      }
    },
    mutations: {
      spinIt(state) {
        return (state.controls.spin = !state.controls.spin);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

**component**:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="spin">
            <span @click="spinIt">SPIN</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  import {mapMutations} from 'vuex';
  import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';

  export default {
    name: 'Stake',
    computed: {
      ...mapMutations(['spinIt']),
      ...mapGetters(['isSpinning'])
    }
  }

</script>
```

Comment: has my answer solved your problem? If yes, then please mark as resolved.

Answer (score 2):

First you need restructure the `Vuex` instance by the following:

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    stats: {
      controls: {
        spin: false
      }
    },
  },
  getters: {
    isSpinning: state => {
      return state.stats.controls.spin;
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    spinIt(state) {
      return (state.stats.controls.spin = !state.stats.controls.spin);
    }
  }
});
```

Now you will access the `getters` and `mutations`.

After that, move the `mapMutations` into the `methods` block in your `Spin.vue`:

```
<script>
  import {mapMutations} from 'vuex';
  import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';

  export default {
    name: 'Stake',
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters(['isSpinning'])
    },
    methods: {
      ...mapMutations(['spinIt'])
    }
  }

</script>
```